# How to replace all pixels of a certain RGB value with another value in opencv4nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, opencv, image-processing

I used opencv4nodejs and nodejs for that,

I am trying to get image RGB value and replace specific RGB values in a specific index and create a 2d array.

```
const color_map = [[255,255,0], [255,0,0], [0,255,255], [0,255,0], [0,0,0]];

const input_image = cv.imread("Data/IMG/train_labels/0.png");

let index = 0

function form_2D_label(mat) {
    const image = mat.cvtColor(cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB);
    const imageBuffer = mat.getData();
    const ui8 = new Uint8Array(imageBuffer);

    const imageData = new Array((image.rows * image.cols))

    for (let i = 0; i < ui8.length; i += 3) {
        imageData[index] = [ui8[i], ui8[i + 1], ui8[i + 2]];
        for (const [index, element] of color_map.entries()) { // enumerate color map
             // console.log(index, element);
             // I am trying todo if imageData[index] value = [255, 255, 0] as 0, if [255, 0, 0] as 1, if [0, 255, 255] as 2 like this..
        }

        console.log(imageData[index]) // [255, 255, 0] / [255, 0, 0] like this
        index++;
    }

    return imageData;

}

const test = form_2D_label(input_image);
console.log(test);
```

current output

```
[
[ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 255, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 255, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ],[255, 255, 0]
]
```

expected one

```
[
[ 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 0 ]
]
```

Comment: `color_map` has only so many values, what is the expected behaviour in case neither of the elements match?

Comment: input image has all five color map values...
I give only some examples for current output...
if current output like this expected output will be above mention output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems with your question.

First of all `color_map` only has 5 elements, yet the expected result has index from 0 to 5 (6 elements), I assume that was a mistake and you just want the real indexes.

Second of all nowhere in your code is the value `index` assigned so I'm just gonna assume, it's the next available index, and use `push` property instead.

Since you don't actually want to return multidimentional array but just the 2d array of indexes, there is no point in returning the `imageData`.

Granted the condition you explained in the comments section that color map values will be the only things present you could try to do:

```
const color_map = [[255,255,0], [255,0,0], [0,255,255], [0,255,0], [0,0,0]];

function form_2D_label(mat) {
    const image = mat.cvtColor(cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB);
    const imageBuffer = mat.getData();
    const ui8 = new Uint8Array(imageBuffer);

    const imageData = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < ui8.length; i += 3) {
        imageData.push([ui8[i], ui8[i + 1], ui8[i + 2]]);
        console.log(imageData[imageData.length - 1])
    }

    return [imageData.map(el => color_map.findIndex(color => arrayEquals(color, el)))];
}

function arrayEquals(array1, array2) {
    for (let i = 0, l = array2.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (array2[i] !== array1[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply and show me my mistakes now I fixed my code